# Google Geolocation API: 403 POST Forbidden error

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-geolocation

I'm using Google's geolocation api, but getting this error:

"POST http://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key= //my API key... 403 (Forbidden)"

This is a brand new API key, so I can't imagine I'm hitting my daily limit...

```
    function GeoLocate() {
       var QueryURL = 
           "http://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=" + 
            GeolocationAPIKey;
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: QueryURL,
        }).done(function(response) {
            resolve(response);
        }).fail(function(err) {
            reject(err);
        })
       })
          console.log(response);
       }
```

Comment: Google allows only GET request as far as I know (or at least their Cloud API)... Try sending information in GET. Or read documentation.

Comment: The geolocation wanted it as a POST.  It looks like part of my problem was that the URL needed to be https instead of http!

Comment: Ok, of it helped you, post it as own answer and accept it. It may help other people in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google's geolocation API requires https rather than http.

So code from above is corrected by just adding an 's' to line 3:

```
 function GeoLocate() {
   var QueryURL = 
       "https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=" + 
        GeolocationAPIKey;
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: QueryURL,
    }).done(function(response) {
        resolve(response);
    }).fail(function(err) {
        reject(err);
    })
   })
      console.log(response);
   }
```